# XMLHttpRequest.onreadystatechange not getting called on PUT operation

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have registered a handler for XMLHttpRequest.onreadystatechange and it works great when I perform a `GET` request.

However it is not called at all when I do a `PUT` request (on firefox).

I want to notify the user that the put was successful, how can I force firefox to call the state handler?

Comment: you need paste your code firstly. maybe you can check or debug by develop tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bit stupid of me but in the end it turns out the problem was on the server side. There was a miscommunication and the request just hung which of course means firefox didn't trigger state changes.

Works now.